# Tried to generate PGP key with seahorse got error: Couldn't generate PGP key, not found

Tags: gnupg, seahorse, pgp

I'm trying to use seahorse to generate a PGP key. When I hit ok then it returns  aerror 
[Couldn't generate PGP Key, not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEVQ7.png) error

What would I need to do to fix this?
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0tUc.png) when I run seahorse in the terminal

The first message labeled seahorse-CRITICAL comes up when I press the button to add a PGP key. 
The second labeled seahorse-MESSAGE comes up when I press create on the page where I enter the name and email.The third comes up when I press okay on the password entry dialog.

Comment: Start `seahorse` from a terminal and see if any more meaningful messages come up.

Comment: I've added the terminal output to the Post

Comment: One of those mentions the time. Is your system clock set correctly? You didn't have the key's expiration date set in the past did you?

Comment: I have Never expires set, but the date seems to be set a year from now.